# CMS which allow different account types with registration via sms

Tags: content-management-system, sms, sms-gateway, profiles, user-registration

I need a CMS which fits the following requirements:

1) It allows to set up registration process in the following way:

a) user inputs his name and phone number;

b) user receives confirming code via sms;

c) user enters the code in input text field;

d) the system checks the confirming code and gives a user login and password.

2) Easy integration with sms gateway.

3) The system should support different account types. All users will have their rooms, but functionality of this room should be based on user's account type. And functionality differs much from one type to another.

5) The system should provide high security.

6) Language is not important - but preferable PHP or Java.

7) No need to have forum, char, RSS, guest book, blog and so on.

8) Free or cheap.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of any CMS out of the box would have SMS user registration support as SMS is mostly a paid service. I would suggest using a CMS that you could add your own SMS service to via a custom plugin. Drupal and Wordpress come to mind but there are many others out there.

As for the SMS part you could use something like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) or go through a SMS Aggregator such as [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com)